# Conditional routing in controller not working Node Express

Tags: node.js, express

I've built some conditional logic to control access to a subdomain (producer.localhost:3000)

Only users with role 'admin' should be able to access the site, everyone else (with role of 'user') should be redirected to their profile page.

This is the code inside `producerController.js` :

```
index = (req, res, next) => {
if ((req.oidc.user['https://localhost:3000.com/roles']).includes("user")){
  res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/user/profile')
} 
else {
  res.render('producer/index')
  };
};
```

The problem is that it redirects for ALL user roles (rather than just those with ‘user’ as a role)

Comment: What is the response structure of localhost/roles?

Comment: added to question for you - I will also add something else I tried

Comment: Does that list don't contain 'user' for admins too?

Comment: no - I've double checked in the console.log of an admin and it simply has : {
  'https://localhost:3000.com/roles': [ 'admin' ],

Comment: Looks like something weird is going on. Have tried swapping the conditions? Like includes("admin") and else part for users?

Comment: thanks added an update to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem like an express issue to me, try something like this

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = require('express');

//Only allows users to continue to route if admin is one of their roles
const adminRoute = (req, res, next) =>{
    if(req.oidc.user['https://localhost:3000.com/roles'].includes('admin'))
        next();
    else
        res.redirect('http://localhost:300/user/profile');
}


//Example use case
//Everything affected by this app.use() (in this case anything underneath it) will only be accessible to users with the admin role
app.use('*', adminRoute)

app.get('/protectedRoute', (req, res) =>{
    res.send('Protected route')
})

//Or you can use it directly inside the route
app.get('/protectedRoute', adminRoute, (req, res) =>{
    res.send('Protected route')
})


app.listen('80', () =>{
    console.log('Listening on port 80')
})
```

This should work 100% of the time, the only logical conclusion is that your if statement isn't returning the proper value.

In which case you can try using

```js
if(array.indexOf('admin') !== -1)
```

Comment: thanks added update to the question

Answer (score 0):

The code shouldn't conflict just put them underneath eachother

```js
//Executes this first
app.use((req, res, next) =>{
   doThing();
   next();
})

//Then executes the next route/use
app.use((req, res, next) =>{
   doOtherThing();
   if(something == false) return res.redirect('https://test.com');
   next();
})

//Lastly if next was called in every use statement before this access route
app.get('/someRoute', (req, res) =>{
   res.send('Accessed some route');
}
```

Not sure if I understand your issue

Comment: I will reword the question to be clearer now I have more info